# maven archetype plugin not applying all properties

Tags: java, maven, archetypes

In a project I'm working on we are also using custom archetypes to make it easier to generate new domains/connectors. After trying to write automated tests to validate these archetypes I came across a problem with the generation of these archetypes. For some reason not all properties that are provided either using the `-D` flags or using the interactive mode are applied to the generated `pom.xml`

The archetype looks [like this](https://github.com/openengsb/openengsb-framework/tree/master/tooling/archetypes/domain).

Running [this command](http://pastebin.com/2rc70NPm) results in [this pom.xml](http://pastebin.com/9eDLtnP3) being generated. It applied the fields for the properties `${package}` and `${domainInterface}`, but not the ones for `groupId`, `artifactId`, `version` and `name`.

So my question is, am I doing something wrong, is the archetype broken or is that a bug in the maven archetype plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried reproducing this by cloning the GitHub repository, installing the archetype locally and then running your command.

```
git clone https://github.com/openengsb/openengsb-framework.git
cd openengsb-framework/tooling/archetypes/domain
vim pom.xml
```

Removed the parent pom reference and then:

```
mvn clean install
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.openengsb.tooling.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=org.openengsb.tooling.archetypes.domain -DarchetypeVersion=3.0.0-SNAPSHOT -DgroupId=org.openengsb.domain -DartifactId=org.openengsb.domain.foodomain -Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -Dname=FooDomain -DopenengsbVersion=3.0.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackage=org.openengsb.domain.foodomain -DdomainInterface=FooDomain -DdomainName=foodomain -DinteractiveMode=false
cd org.openengsb.domain.foodomain/
cat pom.xml
```

Renders this pom.xml (only part of it pasted here):

```
  <properties>
    <bundle.symbolicName>org.openengsb.domain.foodomain</bundle.symbolicName>
    <bundle.namespace>org.openengsb.domain.foodomain</bundle.namespace>
    <domain.name>FooDomain</domain.name>
  </properties>

  <groupId>org.openengsb.domain</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.openengsb.domain.foodomain</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>FooDomain</name>
```

Comment: So it's the parent reference in the archetype pom that's causing this strange behaviour?

Comment: Not sure, but I didn't want to build _everything_ so I just installed the archetype. Not exactly sure why you get the problem. Have you looked at the archetype files in your local Maven repository?

Comment: Did you try the steps in my answer?

Comment: Yeah I just looked at the jar file in my maven repo and noticed that in src/main/resources/archetype-resources/pom.xml (I believe) the fields for `${groupId}`, `${artifactId}`, `${version}` and `${name}` were missing, i.e. they had static values. I deleted the whole openengsb folder from the repo and I'm currently installing it again to see if that fixed it somehow

Comment: This is what the `archetype-resources/pom.xml` in the `org.openengsb.tooling.archetypes.domain-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` file looks like: [link](http://pastebin.com/nj0uY5Ty)

Comment: Yes, that's your problem right there. Just following my steps should fix it. Good luck!

Comment: Hm, yeah it really fixed it, so thanks. But now it'd be nice to know why exactly it does that, since afaik the parent needs to be there.

Comment: You need the parent. Most likely the version you had in your local repo wasn't the latest? So it might have been some changes made to fix the hardcoded values? Did you download the archetype jars or build them yourself before?

Comment: As I said I completely deleted the openengsb folder in my maven repo, I fetched and merged the latest version of the framework and ran `mvn -U clean install`. After that I still had the archetype with the static values in the pom, and after I did what you suggested and then running `mvn clean install` from within the specific archetype it works as it's supposed to

Comment: Ok, I would create an issue for that project and notify them about the problem

Comment: Yeah I already did and I guess I'm also the one who will have to take care of it. Thanks for your help, guess it would have taken us much longer to figure that out

Comment: Similar issue posted by me some years ago; let me know if you want me to take a look in the plugin sources... http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ARCHETYPE-110?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Comment: I'm currently trying to find the root of this problem. So far I discovered that when I remove the parent-reference in openengsb/tooling/archetypes/pom.xml it works how it's supposed to, so it's either a problem with our framework parent or it really is an issue similar to the one you've described within the plugin itself

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18636/discussion-between-peter-liljenberg-and-szernex)